# How to calculate the standard error of the mean for circular data?

Tags: r, standard-error, circular-statistics

I followed the suggestions here to calculate the SD from circular data in the R circular package: [How to calculate standard deviation of circular data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55616697/how-to-calculate-standard-deviation-of-circular-data)

However, I need the SE of the mean for a number of different points I have for Aspect (aspect for the terrain I am working on).  Can I just divide the SD by the square root of N like I would in linear calculations or do I need to do something else?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not simply divide by the square root of N.

While the standard deviation can be computer as a property of the data, the standard error is a property of a parameter or more precisely attached to a parameter estimate. This means that the way to calculate the standard error of the mean direction of  the von Mises distribution differs from the way to calculate the SE of the wrapped Cauchy.

If we assume that we want the SE of the mean direction of the von Mises, we can use that the likelihood of the mean is also von Mises, with mean equal to the data mean direction, and concentration $R\kappa$, where R is the resultant length, and $\kappa$ is the concentration parameter, where we could fill in an estimate.

We can either use this directly, or transform this to a scale similar to the standard deviation.